# ID of each data type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we find the ID of each Data type in oracle as we find in SQL Server using `user_type_id`?

Comment: What `id` are you looking for?  `all_tab_columns` has the column name and the data type.  But the data type is a string not a numeric identifier.  But you'd normally just want the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I meant every data type has some ID(integer ID). Please see this link, it shows the user_type_id of each data type in SQL, I want to know the ID of each data type in oracle. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee56005c-1e07-4513-a134-4b3856bf6885/usertypeid?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: SQL is a language that is implemented by multiple database engines.  SQL Server is Microsoft's database engine.  That's a SQL Server discussion forum.  Are you assuming that every database engine defines their data dictionary the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you are looking for, but the following queries, give a ton of information. You can filter them down in the where clauses, to get what you need.

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      ALL_TAB_COLUMNS;
    
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      ALL_TABLES;
    
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      ALL_COLL_TYPES;
    
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      ALL_IDENTIFIERS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code associated with each built-in data type by looking it up in Oracle's [built-in data type documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) or by using the `DUMP` function:

```sql
SELECT DUMP( 'abc' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | DUMP('ABC')            |
> | :--------------------- |
> | Typ=96 Len=3: 97,98,99 |
> ```

I.e. A `CHAR` or `NCHAR` are fixed-length character data types and have a code of `96`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9724a8ebd3c913d91512f796fdc84fc)*